# Python 3.2: Making a list of lists of integers in a file

Tags: python, file, list, file-io, python-3.x

So I have a file containing a matrix of integers. I need to read in the contents of the file and store it in a list of lists. I can't quite figure out how I have to do this.

Here is an example of what the file A.txt contains:

```
3,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
11,12,13,14,15,16,17
21,22,23,24,25,26,27
```

And here is my code so far:

```
def main():

    A = open('A.txt')

    Alist = []

    for eachLine in A:





main()
```

So how do I go about doing this? I know I have to use the method readLine() and split() in some way but I'm not sure how. Also it must be a list of integers, not strings. Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any ideas? Explain them and we will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to parse each line into a list of integers, calling `split` to break it up at the commas and then `int` to turn them from strings (like `['3', '7']` into `[3, 7]`), and then accumulate those:

```
with open('A.txt') as f:
    Alist = []
    for line in f:
        part = []
        for x in line.split(','):
            part.append(int(x))
        Alist.append(part)
```

(This uses a `with` statement to open the file, which is the preferred method since it automatically closes your file when you're done with it, even if there's an error in the meantime.)

But notice how we have two loops that are just initializing an empty list and then adding something for each element? That's a very common pattern, so Python has list comprehensions to make them nicer. Let's only do the inner part first:

```
with open('A.txt') as f:
    Alist = []
    for line in f:
        part = [int(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        Alist.append(part)
```

See how it's exactly the same thing? Now we can make it even shorter:

```
with open('A.txt') as f:
    Alist = [[int(x) for x in line.split(',')] for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `map()`:

```
In [1]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
   ...:     lis=[map(int,x.split(",")) for x in f]
   ...:     print lis  
   ...:     
[[3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]
```

or using `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
In [5]: import ast

In [6]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
    lis=[list(ast.literal_eval(x)) for x in f]
    print lis
   ...:     
[[3, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]
```